# Does the Grothendieck group of finitely generated modules form a commutative ring where the multiplication structure is induced from tensor product?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products, algebraic-k-theory

For a commutative ring $R$, let $\mathrm{mod-}R$ denote the category of finitely generated $R$-modules. Let $\mathcal C$ be an abelian, full, isomorphism closed (i.e. $M\cong N$ in $\mathrm{mod-}R$ and $M\in Ob(\mathcal C)\implies N\in Ob(\mathcal C)$) subcategory of $\mathrm{mod-}R$.

The Grothendieck group of $\mathcal C$, usually denoted by $G(\mathcal C)$, is defined as
$$\dfrac{\bigoplus_{X\in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal C)}\mathbb Z[X]}{\langle [A]-[B]+[C] \mid 0\to A \to B \to C\to 0  \text{ is exact}   \rangle }$$
where $[X]$ denotes the isomorphism class of $X$.

Now if for every $M,N\in Ob(\mathcal C)$, we also have $M\otimes_R N\in Ob(\mathcal C)$, then the $\mathbb Z$-module
$$\bigoplus_{X\in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal C)}\mathbb Z[X]$$
can be given a $\mathbb Z$-algebra structure where the ring multiplication is induced by the tensor product. If every module in $\mathcal C$ is flat, then the $\mathbb Z$-submodule $${\langle [A]-[B]+[C] \mid 0\to A \to B \to C\to 0  \text{ is exact}   \rangle }$$ of $\bigoplus_{X\in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal C)}\mathbb Z[X]$ is also an ideal, so the Grothendieck group actually becomes a commutative ring where the product structure is induced from tensor product.

My question is: What happens in case not every module of $\mathcal  C$ necessarily flat? Does the Grothendieck group necessarily become a commutative ring where the product structure is induced from tensor product? I'm particularly interested in the case of $G(\mathrm{mod-}R)$: is it necessarily a commutative ring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $k$ be a field and let $R=k[x]/(x^2)$.  Then every finitely generated $R$-module is a direct sum of copies of $R$ and $R/(x)$, and it is easy to see that $G(\mathrm{mod}R)$ is freely generated as an abelian group by $[R/(x)]$, with $[R]=2[R/(x)]$ (you can see this since there is a homomorphism $G(\mathrm{mod}R)\to\mathbb{Z}$ sending a module to its dimension as a $k$-vector space).  But this group does not form a ring under the tensor product, since $R\otimes R\cong R$ and $R/(x)\otimes R/(x)\cong R/(x)$ so we would need to have both $[R]^2=[R]=2[R/(x)]$ and $[R]^2=(2[R/(x)])^2=4[R/(x)]$.

Comment: thanks ... this might be a stupid question, but is there a chance that $G($mod$R)$ would become a ring with tensor multiplication structure if we took some other coefficient ring than $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: In a sense you're not done, as far as I can see you still need to see why $[R] \neq 0$

Comment: @Max: That's implied by the fact I mentioned that the group is _freely_ generated by $[R/(x)]$.

Comment: Oh my bad I hadn't noticed the word freely !

Comment: @user102248: Not unless the coefficient ring is trivial.  You will always get a module freely generated by $[R/(x)]$, and then the relations $[R/(x)]^2=[R/(x)]$, $[R][R/(x)]=[R/(x)]$, and $[R]=2[R/(x)]$ are easily seen to imply that everything is $0$.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $R$ is a ring such that for every $R$-module $M$ there is a projective resolution $P_\bullet \to M$ of finite length (actually, this condition can be loosened quite a bit as I will note at the end). Then we can define a ring structure on $G(R)$ the Grothendieck group of finitely generated $R$-modules by defining the following product
$$
[A] \cdot [B] = \sum_i (-1)^i \text{Tor}_i(A,B).
$$
Note that if $P$ is a projective $R$-module, then $[A]\cdot[P] = [A \otimes P]$ since the $\text{Tor}_i(A,P)$ vanish for $i >0$.

The way to show this is a little painful. We need to show that

1. This product is independent of choice of resolution,
2. this product is well-defined,
3. this product is symmetric,
4. this product satisfies the ring axioms.

It is in my opinion easier to define this product as a map on $G(R)$ first, though tastes may vary. Fix a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ and let
$$
- \cdot M : G(R) \to G(R),\; [A] \mapsto [A] \cdot M := \sum_i (-1)^i [\text{Tor}_i(A,M)].
$$

Then one can show that this map is independent of the choice of resolution by showing $\text{Tor}_i(-,M)$ is. The well-definedness of the map follows since for any short exact sequende $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ we have a long exact sequence of Tor, which shows $[A] \cdot M - [B] \cdot M + [C] \cdot M = 0$. The symmetry follows from the symmetry of Tor, so $[A] \cdot B = [B] \cdot A$.

From this point it is therefore acceptable to write $[A] \cdot [B]$, and we can prove the ring axioms one by one. For this it is good to note that for an $R$-module $M$ with projective resolution $P_\bullet \to M$ we have
$$
[M] \cdot [N] = \sum_i (-1)^i [\text{Tor}_i(M,N)] = \sum_i(-1)^i H_i(P_\bullet \otimes N) = \sum_i (-1)^i [P_i \otimes N].
$$

This computation involves the nontrivial lemma that in the Grothendieck group we have $\sum_i(-1)^i [C_i] = \sum_i (-1)^i [H_i(C_\bullet)]$ for any *finite* complex $C_\bullet$ in the category.

Then the ring axioms can easily be checked by using properties of the tensor product.

The requirement that every object in the category have a finite projective resolution is actually too strong. If every object has a finite resolution that is $F$-acyclic for a functor $F$ on the category, then it induces a derived morphism on Grothendieck groups. Actually, the resolution need not even be in the category itself. For example for categories of coherent sheaves we almost never have projective resolutions, but in some situations (details omitted on purpose) we may have locally free resolutions, which are $\text{Tor}_i(-, *)$ acyclic, so that we can define the product.

Comment: well thanks , but I do not understand what is the relation of your derived tensor product with my question ... does this derived tensor product naturally turns the Grothendieck group into a commutative ring ?

Comment: @user102248 Yes.

Comment: thanks, I will think why ... btw, more generally, for regular rings of finite Krull dimension, every module has finite projective dimension

Comment: I will take time reading your answer carefully ... but for now, could you kindly give a reference for the fact you mention that in the Grothendieck group, $\sum_i(-1)^i [C_i] = \sum_i (-1)^i [H_i(C_\bullet)]$, for any complex $C_\bullet$ ? also , if possible, could you give some reference as to where I can find the multiplication structure you mention (may be explained in slightly more detail ) ? Thanks

Comment: @user102248 That one is not so hard to see. Suppose $C_\bullet$ is a complex with maps $d_i : C_i \to C_{i - 1}$. Then for every $i$ we have an exact sequence $0 \to \text{ker} d_i \to C_i \to \text{im} d_i \to 0$ which shows that $[C_i] = [\text{ker} d_i] + [\text{im} d_i]$ in the Grothendieck group. But also $[H^i(C_\bullet)] = [\text{ker} d_i] - [\text{im} d_{i + 1}]$ by definition. Play around with the indices of the two sums a bit and you will see that it works.

Comment: @user102248 as for a reference for this structure, this is something that's often done in derived categories. I like the book by Huybrechts for that. The $K$-book is a nice reference but doesn't read very well imo. If you know some french you can read the article by Borel and Serre http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1958__86__97_0.pdf which is pretty much where the Grothendieck group was first introduced. They discuss the mulitplicative structure as well. However, they take a slightly different approach where they work only on vector bundles and introduce the product by isomorphism.

Comment: I see ... thanks for the references (unfortunately I don't know any french ), btw which book by Huybrechts are you referring to ?

Comment: @user102248 http://www.mi-ras.ru/~akuznet/homalg/Huybrechts_Fourier-Mukai_transforms.pdf page 79 has an argument in the language of derived categories. Most of the argument works if you replace $D(X)$ by $G(R)$.

Comment: Hello ... sorry to bother you on this again, but I had a few more questions: (1) If $R$ is a regular local ring, then $G(R$-mod$)\cong \mathbb Z$ as groups , now are they also isomorphic as rings with the product structure as you've defined ? (2) If $R$ is regular, then the canonical inclusion map $K_0(R)\to G_0(R)$ is actually an isomorphisms of groups. Now $K_0(R)$ already has a product structure induced by tensor product, and again $G_0(R)$ has a product structure under your definition ... so do the canonical map become a ring homomorphism ? ... (contd.)

Comment: (3) you say that if we're trying to give a product structure on $G(\mathcal C)$ and $\mathcal C$ have a $F$-acyclic resolution for every object, where $F:\mathcal C \to \mathcal C$  is a left or right exact functor ... then can you actually spell out your product structure ?  (4) The way you define a product structure on $G(R$-mod $)$ doesn't actually work ... you would at-least want that $Tor^R_n(M,N)$ are all finitely generated whenever $M,N$ are ... however  that doesn't hold unless $R$ is Noetherian ... do you have a fix for that ? (o.w. I'm okay to assume $R$ is Noetherian )

Comment: @user102248 (1) The isomorphism I'm familiar with generally looks like $G(R) \to \Bbb Z \oplus \text{Pic}(R)$ that sends a class $[M] \mapsto (\text{rank}M, \text{det}M)$. The ring structure then looks like $(a,A)(b,B) = (ab, A^{\otimes b} \otimes B^{\otimes a})$. Indeed if the Picard group vanishes then $\text{det}M = R$ and the ring structure just becomes $(a,R)(b,R) = (ab,R)$. This corresponds to the usual ring structure on $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: For (1), I'm familiar with the procedure that $G_0(R)$ surjects onto $\mathbb Z$ and that $[R]$ generates $G_0(R)$ which I guess amounts to the same thing you just said ... b.t.w, never mind point (3), I just realized that to make $R$-mod into an abelian category, you do need $R$ to be Noetherian ... if $R$ is not Noetherian, the definition of Grothendieck group is usually taken to be slightly different .. .

Comment: (2) If $R$ is regular (and Noetherian, as you state in (3) (I believe these conditions are all you need, maybe you need more. I've only ever used this contruction in nice situations where everything works.)) then indeed the canonical inclusion map becomes a ring isomorphism. This happens for essentially the same reason as illustrated above, namely that any f.g. module $M$ has a finite projective resolution $P_\bullet \to M$, and then $[M] = \sum_i (-1)^i[P_i]$ in the Grothendieck group of f.g. modules.

Comment: @user102248 That does amount to the same thing. I guess the rank morphism is an isomorphism in that case. But it may be fun to try out some rings where the Picard group is nontrivial.

Comment: okay I see ... will try to work out the details ... btw , in my previous comment , I meant to ignore point (4) where I raise the issue of being Noetherian, not point (3) ... it would be helpful if you could clarify point (3)

Comment: @user102248 The product is spelled out in the answer. Do you mean that you want me to show the ring axioms are satisfied? I won't do that. It is not too hard but it is tedious. The essence is to show that $\text{Tor}$ is symmetric. I'm sure you can find a reference using double complexes.

Comment: Oh no no, I didn't mean for you to show the ring axioms ... I was saying like what if $F$ is not a functor of the form $-\otimes B$ ? And it seems you would need a functor corresponding to every object in $\mathcal C$ ...

Comment: @user102248 Oh I see. The statement goes something like this. Let $F : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ be a right exact functor and suppose every object $A \in \mathcal A$ has an $F$-acyclic resolution $P_\bullet \to A$. Suppose further that there are abelian subcategories $\mathcal A_0 \subset \mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B_0 \subset \mathcal B$ such that for every $A \in \mathcal A_0$, $\text{L}^i F(A) \in \mathcal B_0$ and $\text{L}^i F(A) = 0$ for all but finitely many $i$. THEN we have a group homomorphism $LF : G(\mathcal A_0) \to G(\mathcal B_0) : [A] \mapsto \sum_i (-1)^i \text{L}^i[A]$.

Comment: The idea is that the resolution you use to construct this thing does not have to be contained in your starting category. For example, every coherent sheaf has an injective resolution of quasicoherent sheaves, but the Grothendieck group of Qcoh sheaves is zero (I think). The way you construct the direct image functor on the Grothendieck group of *coherent* sheaves is to use an injective resolution of *quasi-coherent* sheaves.

Answer (score 4):

Take $R=\mathbb {Z/4}$, and assume $\otimes$ induces a distributive multiplication.

Then we have $\mathbb{Z/2} + \mathbb{Z/2}= \mathbb Z/4$ from the usual extension.

However, if you multiply by $\mathbb Z/2$, you get on the LHS $\mathbb Z/2 + \mathbb Z/2$ and on the RHS $\mathbb Z/2$, which would imply that $\mathbb Z/2 = 0$.

However, if you look at the map defined on finitely generated $\mathbb Z/4$-modules (which are therefore finite) by $f:X\mapsto \ln |X|$, then it extends linearly to $\bigoplus_{X} \mathbb Z \cdot[X]\to (\mathbb R, +)$ and whenever $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact, we have $|B| = |C||A|$ so $f(A)-f(B)+f(C)=0$, therefore $f$ actually induces a map $G(\mathrm{mod}-R)\to (\mathbb{R},+)$ that sends $\mathbb Z/2$ to $\log 2 \neq 0$

Therefore $\otimes$ does not induce a distributive multiplication on $G(\mathrm{mod}-R)$ (actually if you look at it closely you don't even need to assume distributivity, because it would automatically follow)